# Partition hidden after installation of linux

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, partition-recovery, boot-partition

I tried to install a linux on a partition I made and couldn't complete the process due to some technical problems. I then aborted the installation and went back into booting via windows 8. Now the partition i had reserved for linux is greyed out and i am looking for a solution to get it back.

Comment: You need to get the data back or just the partition back to NTFS so that windows can recognize it?

Comment: The partition is still there. Windows just doesn't know what in the world it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are [**many disk partitioning softwares**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software) that can help you.

The easiest way to get your partition back is to run live linux CD/DVD if you have it and start GParted or some other partition software that is on live CD and format partition back to NTFS.

Also there is [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) - a Windows file system driver for the Ext2, Ext3, and Ext4 file systems. It allows Windows to read Linux file systems natively, providing access to the file system via a drive letter that any program can access.

There are applications that can read linux partitions like [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) or [Ext2explore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/).